# Interpretation of multiple factor variables in linear regression

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression

I couldn't find a similar forum post, where multiple factor variables are included in a regression, which all have multiple base groups. I would like to make my question clear with a short example with a regression equation.

Let's assume we would like to predict console prices (Y) while using the age of the consoles as an independent variable, as well as two color dummies. There are in total 15 colors and only dummy variables of two of them are included, which are 1 when the console is blue (gold) and 0 otherwise.

${\rm price}_i\ =\ \beta_0\ +\ \beta_1{\rm age}_i+\beta_2{\rm blue}_i+\beta_3{\rm gold}_i\ +\upsilon_i$

Let's assume blue as well as gold are significant, what is the correct interpretation of blue?:

1. "Consoles which have the color blue have on average a $\beta_2$
   higher/lower price than consoles with different colors, keeping
   everything else constant"
2. "Consoles which have the color blue have on average a $\beta_2$
   higher/lower price than consoles with different colors, **except
   gold**, keeping everything else constant"

I am unsure if I need the "except gold" and couldn't find an answer elsewhere.

Please let me know, when you have suggestions how I can improve my question.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the **except gold** part. Notice you are comparing $$\mathbb{E}(price_i|age_i, blue_i = 1) - \mathbb{E}(price_i|age_i, blue_i = 0) .$$ $blue_i = 1 \implies gold_i = 0$. So the "everything else equal" has to fix $gold_i = 0$.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I need some clarification. As I have mentioned, we assume to have in total 15 colors and only two are included in the regression model. I thought when ${blue}_i=\ 1$ then all other 14 colors, also ${gold}_i$, have to be 0. Therefore, I thought the coefficient of ${blue}_i$ has to be interpreted to all other 14 colors and I don't understand why I only interpret it to the remaining 13 colors, not included in the model. If I would include 14 out of 15 colors, would the coefficient of the 14 colors only be interpreted against the single not included color?

Comment: "If I would include 14 out of 15 colors, would the coefficient of the 14 colors only be interpreted against the single not included color?"
Yes. The interpretation of dummy variables is always with respect to the ommitted category. You have to set some color to be your baseline, to which you compare the presence of the others.